# Material UI Textfield not working on mobile safari browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

EDIT: Fixed the issue by adding this to index.css

```
input { -webkit-user-select:text;}
```

I currently have a material UI box and within the box i have textfields with an onChange handler. The TextFields work fine on any other browser, but users have reported having issues with the safari browser on mobile, where they can click on the input and type, but nothing is changing in the box and it remains empty.

This is the code for the textfield and the onChange handler.

```
 const [personalDetails, setPersonalDetails] = useState({
   fullName: "",
   email: "",
   phoneNumber: "",
 });

 const handlePersonalDetailsChange = (event) => {
   const { name, value } = event.target;
   setPersonalDetails({ ...personalDetails, [name]: value });
 };


               <Box
                   component="form"
                   sx={{
                     "& .MuiTextField-root": { m: 1, width: "100%" },
                   }}
                   noValidate
                   autoComplete="off"
                 >
                   <div>
                     <TextField
                       required
                       id="outlined-required"
                       label="Full Name"
                       name="fullName"
                       value={personalDetails.fullName}
                       onChange={handlePersonalDetailsChange}
                       type={"text"}
                     />
                   </div>
                   <div>
                     <TextField
                       required
                       id="outlined-required"
                       label="Email"
                       name="email"
                       type={"email"}
                       value={personalDetails.email}
                       onChange={handlePersonalDetailsChange}
                     />
                   </div>
                   <div>
                     <TextField
                       required
                       id="outlined-required"
                       label="Phone Number"
                       name="phoneNumber"
                       type={"number"}
                       value={personalDetails.phoneNumber}
                       onChange={handlePersonalDetailsChange}
                     />
                   </div>
                 </Box>
```

Any idea on the issue will be appreciated.

Comment: Can't reproduce, but some field type might not be supported in old version of Safari. See [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/?search=type%3D%22email%22) for more information.

Comment: _"EDIT: Fixed the issue..."_: If your problem is solved, I suggest to [write an answer to you question yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Code example for styled components]

Like the post, my mui text input freezes in safari(mobile and desktop).
The cause is that I have disabled user-select by css for all elements.
I suppose Chrome and Firefox are smart enough to allow user interactions anyways. And Safari just honors the css regardless.

The solution is therefore simple(as the original post suggested), for the text input and any child within, allow user-select.

```
-webkit-user-select: text;
user-select: text;

& * {
    -webkit-user-select: text;
    user-select: text;
}
```